# Is there a way to supply the columnDefs to ui-grid with a promise?

Tags: angular-promise, angular-ui-grid

The data for the ui-grid seems to support a promise of the data, but the columnDef option does not seem to. If the data coming in is dynamic and the column defs are also loaded dynamically how can the columns definition be specified with a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply your columnDefs the promise's return value in your .then() handler:

```js
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: [ ... ]
};

ColumnService.getColumns()
  .then(function (columnDefs) {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
  });
```